# Extjs combobox to display store records based on a property

Tags: extjs, combobox, model, store

I am new to Sencha and my question is the following:

by calling the store 'Media' in a combobox:

`xtype: 'combobox',
  itemId: 'mediaPicker',
  store: Ext.create('web.store.Media'), 
  fieldLabel: 'Image',
  emptyText: 'Choose an Image'`

I receive a list of media as expected, but, how can I receive a list of only images, based on the following property in the store's model:

`{
   name: 'type',
   type: 'int'
 }`,

where type == 1 for images.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share a fiddle and your ExtJs Version. You need to pass a filter to the store, either by using the combobox or directly at the store - you may want to look at the filterBy function of the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a filter to your store.

Change `store: Ext.create('web.store.Media')` to something like

```
store: Ext.create('web.store.Media',{
    filters: [{
        property: 'type',
        value: 1
        }])
```

Note: I'm not sure whether the above will do a strict === or a loose == comparison. If it's not working for you then you can specify the filter on the store using a function. Check out the store filtering documentation.

Comment: As far as I know, it does neither === nor == by default, only `.toString().startsWith()`. You have to add the [`exactMatch:true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.util.Filter.html#cfg-exactMatch) config to the filter to get ==, and you cannot achieve === using the property, only through a function. You can see the whole mess for yourself [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22l2).

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement this code :

```
var my_images_store  =  new Ext.data.JsonStore({ 
                        url: 'myfilefunc.php'   
                        ,autoLoad: true
                        ,fields:[id,desc]
                        ,root: 'images'
                });
```

`

**url:** put here the url to your business logic (**php** function for example)
**fields:** name of the fields returned by the resultset 
**root:**  name of the resultset

Resultset example :`

```
{
    images: [
        {id: '1', desc:'x'},
        {id: '2', desc:'y'}
    ]
}
```

`